# How to get DPInst? Can't find it in WDK 8.1 install

Tags: windows, drivers, wdk, dpinst

I downloaded the latest WDK and have been looking everywhere for DPInst. Did they separate it into a different package for 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in *[DPInst Localization Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544784(v=vs.85).aspx)*.

In the installation directory, look under `redist\DIFx\dpinst`, choose appropriate language and platform in subdirectory below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this may help: [Get dpinst.exe for 64 bit](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/where-to-download-dpinstexe-64-bit/164ca07a-f699-4f57-8132-9d722efb3045)